# I accidentally closed my cmd and i cant re run my Django server again

Tags: python, django

when I open my cmd again it doesnt run my server and shows this error

C:\Users\16478\my_tennis_club>py manage.py runserver
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\16478\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe manage.py runserver'

I even tried activating my env again but it didn't work out

Comment: Probably some resource was left open. Did you try to restatrt your computer?

Comment: i did still didn't change anything

Comment: Have you not created a virtual environment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.